# How to ensure heavy duty tasks on Meteor js backend are executed?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, meteor, fibers

It seems like my heavy duty tasks (running a few minutes once a day to recalculate some stuff, scheduled with SyncedCron) are getting interrupted and thus deliver incorrect/weird results. This happens now, that my website has multiple concurrent users.

Apparently, Meteor handles micro-tasks (like the ones from clients) very (https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection/issues/248) well but might "starve" big tasks. What can I do?

Comment: Can you maybe add some code example on your heavy duty task? It would help to understand what you are exactly doing and maybe improve the code as well.

Comment: It is quite long, one of them stores some KPIs. One of the KPIs is the average number of questions users have answered. I am sure we could make the code more efficient, but I would love to know how I can ensure the task is not "starved". What happens is, it just takes some really odd number for some of the KPIs, sometimes. How can I do that? @Jankapunkt